# Can't connect to any wifi network on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: wireless

I've been having problems with wifi since I dual booted my laptop a couple of months ago. They usually went away after rebooting it but now it doesn't connect to any network anymore. I tried changing the DNS but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe your WiFi card is dead, on some computer it is super easy to change: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/346854/how-to-upgrade-or-replace-your-pcs-wireless-card/amp/

Answer (score 0):

try one or all of the following:

Restart network manager:
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Rescan for available wifi's:
iwlist  scan

Turn wifi on and off
nmcli radio wifi off && sleep 5 && nmcli radio wifi on